# gvisGauge in R display percent sign

Tags: r, display, googlevis

I was able to plot by using gvisGauge but I need to add percent sign on graph (becasue the numbers are percent) and display majorTicks on the graphs. How can I do that? Please help. If you have also suggestion to make the graph fancier, I really appreaciate.
Thank you. 
Data set below

```
gauge=data.frame(motnh=c("jan","feb","march","april","may","june"
,"july","augost","sept"),percent_s=c(-0.1,0,0.03,-0.06,-0.15,-0.39
,0.36,-0.53,-0.68))
```

This what ı got so far;

```
gauge_plot=gvisGauge(gauge, 
                 options=list(min=-1, max=1, redFrom=-1,
                              redTo=-0.3, yellowFrom=-0.3, yellowTo=0.3,
                              greenFrom=0.3, greenTo=1, width=800, 
                               height=600))
plot(gauge_plot)
```